# View Access 2007 Database Table Contents using VB.net

Tags: database, vb.net

I am trying to display the contents of a table from an Access 2007 Database inside a List-view Box.

I am  using a Combo Box to select the user I wish to see the details about:

```
    Private Sub Admin_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ReadUsers()

    con.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=E:\Computing\Projects\Login\Login\bds.accdb;")

    con.Open()

    Sql = "Select * From Clients"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, con)

    da.Fill(ds, "Clients")
    MaxRows = ds.Tables("Clients").Rows.Count
    intCounter = -1

    ComboBoxClients.DisplayMember = "ClientName"
    ComboBoxClients.ValueMember = "ID"
    ComboBoxClients.DataSource = ds.Tables("Clients")
```

Then inside the List View:

```
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim Test As Integer

    ListView1.Clear()

    For i = 0 To MaxRows - 1
        Test = ds.Tables("Clients").Rows(i).Item("ClientName")

        If Test = ComboBoxClients.SelectedValue Then
            For intCounter As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables("Clients").Columns.Count - 1
                ListView1.Columns.Add(ds.Tables("Clients").Columns(intCounter).ColumnName, 80, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
            Next

            Dim ListItem = New ListViewItem

            ListItem = ListView1.Items.Add(ds.Tables("Clients").Rows(i).Item(0))
            ListItem.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("Clients").Rows(i).Item(1))
            ListItem.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("Clients").Rows(i).Item(2))
            ListItem.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("Clients").Rows(i).Item(3))
            ListItem.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("Clients").Rows(i).Item(4))

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The listview box currently doesn't display anything:
[image: The listview box currently doesn't display anything]

Any help would be great, thanks.

ListView1 Revision:

```
    Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim Test As Integer
    Dim ListItem = New ListViewItem
    ListView1.Clear()

    For i = 0 To MaxRows - 1
        Test = ds.Tables("Clients").Rows(i).Item("ClientName")

        If Test = ComboBoxClients.SelectedValue Then
            For intCounter As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables("Clients").Columns.Count - 1
                ListView1.Columns.Add(ds.Tables("Clients").Columns(intCounter).ColumnName, 80, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
            Next

            ListItem.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("Clients").Rows(i).Item(0))

            ListItem.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("Clients").Rows(i).Item(1))
            ListItem.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("Clients").Rows(i).Item(2))
            ListItem.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("Clients").Rows(i).Item(3))
            ListItem.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("Clients").Rows(i).Item(4))

            ListView1.Items.Add(ListItem)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line ...

```
ListItem = ListView1.Items.Add(ds.Tables("Clients").Rows(i).Item(0))
```

... is not actually adding the ListItem to ListView1. After you declare and set up ListItem, *then* add it to the ListView control:

```
' ...
ListItem.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("Clients").Rows(i).Item(3))
ListItem.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("Clients").Rows(i).Item(4))

ListView1.Items.Add(ListItem)
```

Alternatively, I've found it easier to populate a ListView control like this:

```
Dim items() As String = {dr("customer_id").ToString, _
                         dr("id").ToString, _
                         dr("name").ToString, _
                         dr("address1").ToString, _
                         dr("city").ToString, _
                         dr("state").ToString, _
                         dr("zip_code").ToString}

Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(items)

ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
```

Comment: I'm not fully understanding you. If the line doesn't work what do I replace it with? 

I have tryed that code also and doesn't work.

Thanks